# An example of connected components in an undirected graph

Tags: graph

I am doing an algorithm problem about finding connected components in an undirected graph.
The input is a list of edges stores in (source target), and the output is (vertex,label).
source is an integer representing id of source vertex, 
target is an integer representing id of target vertex,
vertex is vertex id,
label is the label of a connected component to which vertex belongs.

Here are two examples:
Example 1.
input:

```
0 1
1 2
3 1
```

output:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(2, 0)
```

Example 2.
input:

```
0 3
4 5
```

output:

```
(3, 0)
(4, 4)
(5, 4)
```

In my understanding, for the 1st example, all vertex connect to 1, so the graph has one connected components, so the result should be

```
(0,0)
(1,0)
(2,0)
(3,0)
```

but the answer does not have (3,0).

For the 2nd example, 0 connect to 3, 4 connect to 5, there are two connected components. The result should be

```
(0,0)
(3,0)
(4,4)
(5,4)
```

but the answer does not have (0,0)

I am not sure do I misunderstanding something that the result is unequal to the output it gives..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come answer my silly question again... The main point is those two input is a same graph. And the label should be the smallest vertex in the component.